# Error al servir JavaScript Windows Server 2012 IIS 6.2

Tags: javascript, windows, asp, iis, servidor

Hola tengo un Windows Server 2008 con IIS 6.1 en el cual esta alojado un sitio web en ASP, la pagina esta correiendo perfecto y los javascripts son servidos correctamenta:
https://casper09.zip2tax.com/website/pagescountries/canada/index/canadamap.js

Pero en un Windows Server 2012 con IIS 6.2 los javascripts no son correctamente servidos:
https://frank02.zip2tax.com/website/pagescountries/canada/index/canadamap.js

Ya prove varias soluciones. Guardando el js como ANSI, configurantdo el lenguaje de scripting por defecto en IIS para que sea JScript, pero no ha funcionado. 
No se si se trata de problema de configuracion del servidor o es el codigo. aunque el codigo funciona bien en el servidor casper09.

Ideas? muchas gracias.

Comment: dudo que el fallo de tus archivos JS tenga que ver con el servidor puesto que asumo que solo sirves JS que se ejecuta en el cliente

Comment: la cuestion es que el mismo JS es servido correctamente en otro servidor. Ya verifique la sintaxis del JS en un sitio en linea y todo aparece bien tambien.

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto el problema, Encontre que el javascript contenia el siguiente caracter "<%" y esto corresponde a una etiqueta de cdigo ASP. Dado que mi web site es un sitio de ASP, el servidor interpretaba eso como una etiqueta de codigo ASP, aun cuando el archivo era un javascript (*.js). La forma en que lo resolvi fue:

1) Click derecho en la Application pool correspondiente y seleccionar, Configuracion avanzada.
2) En ".NET Framework version" lo cambie a "4.0".
3) En "Enable 32 bits" le coloque "True".
4) En "Managed Pipeline mode" le coloque "Integrated".

Una vez hecho esto agregue/modifique el  web.config con lo siguiente:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
        <add name="ASP-Classic-in-js" path="*.js" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="bitness64" />
</handlers>
```

Despues de eso reinicie el application pool y tambien el website.